# How to find a survivable shortest-path tree in a directed graph

Tags: algorithm, tree, shortest-path

How do I find a survivable shortest-path tree in a directed graph where each directed edge is positively weighted?

The tree may not include all the nodes of the graph and "shortest-path" means the maximal distance from the source to any destination is minimized; and "survivable" means that for the pruned graph by the removal of the directed edges of the tree, another tree can be found.

Comment: I am not sure I understand completely your problem, can you formalize it better please? From what I understand, it seems related to [Steiner trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem), but then again, I might be completely misunderstanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: I don't understand "shortest-path tree", please define it, what is source/destination? I also think that providing an example would be very helpful.

Comment: I've plotted an example graph, but I am not able to attach because of lack of reputations. It's not exactly a Steiner tree, where the sum of the edges in the tree is minimal, while in my case, I want to find a tree _T_ that minimizes the maximal distance of each source-destination path. The Dijkstra's algorithm could do. However, it could not guarantee another tree to be found in the remaining graph. From the final result, two arc-disjoint trees should be found with one of them achieves minimal [Height of tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) in terms of distance. @amit

Comment: Here, the source is the root of the tree, and the set of destinations includes all the leafs, and may include [Internal nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) . From another aspect, the tree is rooted with the source and includes but not limited to all the destinations. The shortest-path tree means a tree with minimal [Height of tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) in terms of distance. @AdamStelmaszczyk